# Advice On How To Securely Manage [Client] Server Details Across Team?

Tags: project-management, development-process, team, security

Does anybody have any advice on this? I currently work as a kind of lead developer/team leader and we have some remote team members and sometimes a contractor or two. At times, the entire team might be working on a large project and server details are usually managed by the entire team.

What is the best practice way to deal with this? Is there something I'm missing? I can't see anyway to have somebody access a server without the details. Also, I'm considering the security protection they have on their machines, should I be ensuring certain things happen to the data like encryption, shredding.

Should I use a 'company' proxy for connections?

Please advise!

Comment: What kind of servers are you using? Windows based or *nix / Linux based? Are you more interested in securing access (like using OpenVPN which is free and very flexible) or the data (you don't want users to be able to copy the project information etc.). What kind of VCS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SSH keys. They would be the best choice in this case. No passwords necessary and access can be securely removed afterwards.

Also don't forget about using a VPN (virtual private network). [LogMeIn has Hamachi<sup>2</sup>](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) which is very straight forward to setup and work with.

Comment: Hi Josh, do you have any more details like where I should look to set this up. Some are on linux, and others windows. I just need something I can research for this type of application. I can't find anything in Google. Thanks.